# Apple Music Library Does Not Sync Correctly Between Two Macs

Tags: macos, music.app

I use a Mac mini as a server and an iMac to work on. I maintain my music collection on the iMac, but I regularly copy the chances over to the Mac mini using an AppleScript with a `rsync` command.

This used to work fine for the time I was using iTunes. Now, under Catalina, changes to the library are not noticed by the Apple Music App on the Mac mini.

I know the `Music Library` file is updated correctly, and also the individual albums and songs get copied to the Mac mini just like they should. For example, Roon is running on the Mac mini too, and it notices the changes. But the Apple Music App just shows the status of the collection of the time where I first copied the whole collection to the Mac mini.

Are there some cache files somewhere I have to take care for? So far, the AppleScript syncs the folders `/Users/User/Music/iTunes` and `/Users/User/Music/Music` (only from iMac to Mac mini).

Comment: There was an app Syncopation from Sonzea that ketpt iTunes library in sync I suspect it does not work now. The way I used lkater is to use shared library ie the music only on one machine and it shares its library so iTunes on the other can see it

Comment: Inside the iTunes folder is a folder called "Automatically add to iTunes." (~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music) I've never used this but perhaps if you put the music files there?

Comment: @SteveChambers I think this is for manual addition of music. I have no idea how I could collect changes like rating music or editing playlists in that folder.